# Is erasing element after before_begin() defined in an empty std::forward_list?

Tags: c++, c++11, forward-list

Does this code have defined behaviour in the C++ standard library?

```
std::forward_list<T> list;
list.erase_after(list.before_begin());
```

Intuition would say no, but I haven't been able to locate the exact standards wording for this particular case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The precondition on `erase_after` is:

> `iterator erase_after(const_iterator position);`
>
> *Requires:* The iterator following `position` is dereferenceable.

So your example has undefined behaviour, because `list` is empty, so `list.before_begin()` is not incrementable, so there is no iterator following it.

If the list has at least one element then `list.erase_after(list.before_begin())` is valid.